# Using Puppeteer how can I get DOMContentLoaded, Load time

Tags: puppeteer

Using Puppeteer how can I get DOMContentLoaded, Load time. It would be great if some once can explain how to access dev tools object, Network from Puppeteer.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are asking about [`window.performance.timing`](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/), here is a simple example how to get this data in Puppeteer:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org');

  const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
    await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
  );
  console.log(performanceTiming);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

But results are quite raw and not meaningful. You should calculate the difference between each value and `navigationStart`, here is a full example of how to do it (code comes from this [article](https://michaljanaszek.com/blog/test-website-performance-with-puppeteer)):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const extractDataFromPerformanceTiming = (timing, ...dataNames) => {
  const navigationStart = timing.navigationStart;

  const extractedData = {};
  dataNames.forEach(name => {
    extractedData[name] = timing[name] - navigationStart;
  });

  return extractedData;
};

async function testPage(page) {
  await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org');

  const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
    await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
  );

  return extractDataFromPerformanceTiming(
    performanceTiming,
    'domContentLoadedEventEnd',
    'loadEventEnd'
  );
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log(await testPage(page));
  await browser.close();
})();
```